# Can't open database with SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android sqlite returned: error code = 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316191/android-sqlite-returned-error-code-14)

I have used SQLiteAssetHelper class/library to manipulate a database from assets/databases folder like indicated in that [link](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). I did exactly all the instructions, but i still can't access to the database.

```
09-27 19:35:46.417: I/Database(27474): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
09-27 19:35:46.417: E/Database(27474): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.gatec.douaa/databases/data", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
09-27 19:35:46.428: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(27474): could not open database data - unable to open database file
09-27 19:35:46.428: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(27474): copying database from assets...
09-27 19:35:46.447: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(27474): extracting file: 'database.db'...
09-27 19:35:46.477: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27474): Couldn't open data for writing (will try read-only):
09-27 19:35:46.477: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27474): com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/data.zip file in assets or target folder not writable
```

Code:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


    }
```

Any help please? Don't know the source of the problem.

Comment: please post your code.  also make sure that there is a databases/data.zip file in your assets folder.

Comment: database name? "data" or something inside data folder

Comment: @ChrisThompson: Of course that i'm sure that the file is in the directory assets/databases/data.zip

Comment: how you created the database "data"? like u done with sqlite create .....?

Comment: @Munipratap: in fact, it was an .sql file, i converted it to .db file via this website `http://www.jembe.fr/developper/outils/convertion-mysql-sqlite.php` then put the db file in data.zip archive.

Comment: @Munipratap: There is a problem with .db file, i figured it out. Have you a technic to make to convert .sql to .db ?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put your .db file in a .zip ? Please try put it in assets without archived. Or you can try put a little without-problem .db file in zip archive for understanding where problem is.

Comment: The developer of SQLiteAssetHelper library oblige the users to put the db file in a zip file.

Comment: I understand, please try second way to understand where the problem is.

Comment: I detected the problem. The converted .db file is not correct. The conversion tool is very poor. Can't find now how to convert .sql file to .db (or sqlite)...