# Asset/data size limit on android using SQLiteAssetHelper?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Everything was working fine before I added some "big" tables to my file.

I have a table that weights about 2Mo, and now I am getting this error :

> 07-19 00:47:51.210    4703-4703/com.lectem.gecharacters
>   W/SQLiteAssetHelper﹕ copying database from assets... 07-19
>   00:47:51.280    4703-4705/com.lectem.gecharacters E/Database﹕ close()
>   was never explicitly called on database
>   '/data/data/com.lectem.gecharacters/databases/gechar2.sqlite'
>       android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was
>   opened here
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
>               at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.returnDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:408)
>               at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:386)
>               at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:182)
>               at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)

I tried to empty the table, and it works again after this...
I am using the SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox, and the SQLiteAssetHelper library.

[Can't open database with SQLiteAssetHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628014/cant-open-database-with-sqliteassethelper) didn't help.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it works fine on my phone (android 4.1) but the error occurs on my Tablet (android 2.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the readme... https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper
I was compressing my database using gzip, but it seems you really need to use zip for old devices.

> Earlier versions of this library required the database asset to be
>   compressed within a ZIP archive. This is no longer a requirement, but
>   is still supported. Applications still targeting Gingerbread (API 10)
>   or lower should continue to provide a compressed archive to ensure
>   large database files are not corrupted during the packaging process.
>   The more Linux friendly GZIP format is also supported. The naming
>   conventions using the above example are as follows:
>
> ```
> ZIP: assets/databases/northwind.db.zip (a single SQLite database file must be the only file within the archive)
> GZIP: assets/databases/northwind.db.gz
> ```